Find two variables from known modulo equation and arithmetic equation.
Given two equations like these:

$P \bmod Q = 90$
$P - Q = 9900$

How to find $P$ and $Q$ value?
Edit (Using subtition):
$ P \bmod Q = 90 $
$ P = 90 \bmod Q $
$ 9900 + Q = 90 \bmod Q $
Here I'm stuck...
Edit again:
$ 9900 + Q = kQ + 90 $
$ 9810 = kQ - Q $
$ 9810 = Q(k - 1) $
$ Q = \frac{9810}{k-1} $
Here I'm stuck...
Also I have no idea where this come from?
$ P = kQ + 90 $

Well, what have you tried?  Do you know what $P\equiv 90\pmod Q$ means?

@lulu It's about congruence of modulo equation, CMIIW. I'm planning to use subtitution method.

Good idea.  Set that up.  Edit your post to include that set up.  Note:  there are several solutions.

Write $P=kQ+90$ and solve.

@ArturoMagidin What does k mean? Is it something I shall brute force?

It's an integer. So that will lead to one multiplicative equations in two integer unknowns.

I have updated it, so I must find k with brute force method?

I would suggest checking your algebra before doing anything by "brute force".... but this isn't "brute force". This is simple factoring. There are, as was noted, multiple solutions unless you have bounds for $Q$ or $P$ beyond the obvious.

$P\bmod Q=90$ means "the remainder when dividing $P$ by $Q$ is $90$." That means that $P$ equals a multiple of $Q$ plus $90$.  Why are you trying to solve mpdular problems if you don't know what "mod" means?

I know "mod", but I just realized it. I thought this question will be only had one solution where $Q=109$. I thought so because the question was generated by my self where I find two prime numbers P and Q. My hipotesis was, doing so would make only one solution.

From $P\bmod Q=90$ we probably (depending on your definition of the binary mod operator) that $Q\gt 90$ and the remainder when dividing $P$ by $Q$ is $90$. That means there exists a $k$ such that $P=kQ+90$. Plugging into the second equation we get
$$9900 = kQ+90-Q$$
so $(k-1)Q = 9810 = 2\times 3^2\times 5 \times 109$.
This gives you several potential choices for $Q$, each leading to a solution.

$P - Q = 9900 \implies 90 \equiv P \equiv 9900 \pmod Q \implies 9900 \equiv 90 \pmod Q \iff Q \mathrel{|}9900-90=9810.\text{ From this we know that } Q \in \{109, 218, 327, 545, 654, 981, 1090, 1635, 1962, 3270, 4905, 9810\}\text{ and } P = 9900 + Q\text{ which gives us all solutions.}$
